# Why getChild method return ParseTree not ParseRuleContext in ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr4

I want to insert new node to the parse tree that my parser just gets when visiting the tree. The position may be the current node's parent or sibling or just before it, so I need to check if there is a node that matches the rule name of the new node by invoking `getParent` and `getChild` methods in `ParseRuleContext`. `getParent` returns `ParseRuleContext`, but `getChild` returns `ParseTree`. Why the two methods return different types?

BTW, It is also possible that the current node should be replaced by the new node.

What is the best way to implement this kind of modification on parse tree? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parse trees in ANTLR 4 consist of terminal nodes and rule nodes. Since a terminal node (representing a single token) cannot have any children, we know the parent of any `RuleNode` is also a `RuleNode`. `ParserRuleContext` is a particular implementation of `RuleNode`, and a parse tree constructed with `ParserRuleContext` representing the rule nodes only uses that representation for rule nodes, so the parent of a `ParserRuleContext` must also be a `ParserRuleContext`.

The children of a `ParserRuleContext` are instances of either `ParserRuleContext` or `TerminalNode`, and the most derived common interface for these is `ParseTree`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! So I need to cast the child to `ParserRuleContext` by checking its instance (use `instanceof`).

Comment: Normally you would use the generated accessor methods instead. For example, if you have a rule `foo : bar;`, instead of using `if (fooContext.getChild(1) instanceof BarContext)` you would use `if (fooContext.bar() != null)`.

Comment: Yes, I use that when visiting tree. But in the other case, I need to search for a particular node to insert another new node. I don't know what is inside those nodes when searching.

Comment: hi Sam , so if I RuleNode.getParent and Rule.getChild can it give me the grammarRule under which the terminal node is right now ? I mean suppose I want to see the total method declaration if a class how can I check that with the rule node ? Can you please suggest me ?